# Calling onBackPressed from a dialogfragment finishes the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment that has a close button on it.

This dialog is called from two different activities. One uses it as a simple fragment, and one as a dialog fragment.

In its onClick method, I call `requireActivity.onBackPress()` so it will close the dialog.

I don't want to call dismiss, because I have a use case in which I want the calling activity to handle it (show a confirmation dialog).

In the activity that shows it as a dialog fragment, calling the `onBackPress` closes not only the dialog but also finishes the activity :scary_face

Pressing the actual back button just dismisses it though.

Any thoughts on what am I missing here?

Code from the dialog fragment:

```
viewBinding.closeBtn.setOnClickListener {
     requireActivity().onBackPressed()
}
```

Code that launches the dialog fragment

```
SharePatientDialogFragment.newInstance(shareData)
                    .show(context.supportFragmentManager, "share")
```

Comment: Post your code :)

Comment: @gcantoni I added some, although there's really not that much to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `onBackPressed()` of the activity and not from the DialogFragment.

Hence, your activity is closing, and therefore the dialog is also closing.

To fix it, you have to invoke the `onBackPressed()` of the dialog fragment to ensure that the dialog fragment is dismissed.

`Fragment` does not possess an `onBackPressed()` method but the `Dialog` class does, as so you need to check if it's a dialog and then invoke the method if available.

Comment: fragments don't have `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Well, this is the accepted answer, but I want to emphasize. While fragments don't have `onBackPressed` dialog do! So I need to check if this is a dialog and call `dialog?.onBackPressed`, and if a dialog is null I call `activity.onBackPressed()`

Comment: Indeed, I should have made it clear that you need to check if it's in fact a dialog